# Query total number of files and folders on a HFS or APFS volume instantly

Tags: macos, filesystems

The macOS 32 bit API offers a way to query the number of files & folders on a local volume *instantly*, as this information is recorded directly in the HFS volume header, as well as on APFS, FAT and NTFS volumes, apparently.

I like to read these same volumes using a 64 bit API, e.g. using POSIX or BSD calls like `fsstat` or `fsctl` if possible. I cannot find one, though.

I had hoped that `statfs()` would give me this value in its `f_files` struct field:

```
 long    f_files;    /* total file nodes in file system */
```

However, that value is always fixed (0xffffffef) and thus useless.

I understand that the values may not be exactly accurate, but that's not necessary. I only need the value to broadly predict the total search time in advance when scanning the entire volume.

Comment: If you know which utilities provide this data (`df`, perhaps?) you can look at the source code or use something `strace`, `dtrace`, or `truss` to find out the system calls the utility makes to get the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a mac but it seems to work with hfsplus on Linux upon doing a quick test:

```
[root@tuxpad tmp]# dd if=/dev/zero of=filesystem.img bs=1024 count=102400
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.130317 s, 805 MB/s
[root@tuxpad tmp]#
[root@tuxpad tmp]# mkfs.hfsplus filesystem.img
Initialized filesystem.img as a 100 MB HFS Plus volume
[root@tuxpad tmp]#
[root@tuxpad tmp]# mount -o loop filesystem.img /mnt/
[root@tuxpad tmp]#
[root@tuxpad tmp]# ./a.out /mnt
f_type=18475
(Total inodes (f_files) = 4294967295
Free inodes (f_ffree) =4294967278
Total no. of files = (f_files - f_ffree) =17
[root@tuxpad tmp]#
[root@tuxpad tmp]# touch /mnt/file{1..100}
[root@tuxpad tmp]#
[root@tuxpad tmp]# ./a.out /mnt
f_type=18475
(Total inodes (f_files) = 4294967295
Free inodes (f_ffree) =4294967178
Total no. of files = (f_files - f_ffree) =117
```

Code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/vfs.h>    /* or <sys/statfs.h> */

int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
        struct statfs buf = {0};
        int ret = 0;

        ret = statfs(argv[1], &buf);
        if (ret) {
                perror("statfs");
                return -1;
        }

        printf("f_type=%llu\n", buf.f_type);
        printf("(Total inodes (f_files) = %llu\n", buf.f_files);
        printf("Free inodes (f_ffree) =%llu\n", buf.f_ffree);
        printf("Total no. of files = (f_files - f_ffree) =%llu\n", buf.f_files -buf.f_ffree);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works indeed. My error was the RTFM kind - I only looked at f_files but didn't know I need to subtract f_free from it. To compile on macOS, the 3rd include needs to read `#include <sys/mount.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to get the information using `FSGetVolumeInfo`. While that's marked deprecated, it still works in macOS 10.15 regardless. Documentation can be found in the header file (Files.h).